# Only a subset of groups available

Tags: redhat, ldap, groups

I have installed RHEL 6.2 and configured for using LDAP with the setup utility
and I can login.

What is stange is that only three LDAP groups are recognized per user. It is different
groups, even for users that belong to the same groups. The gid range id from 500 to 30000+.

The LDAP server is openldap with SLES using it's standard schema.

I have not to my knowledge configured any limitations or filters, so why does it
pick only three arbitrary groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it out. The defalt schema for RH is not the same as for SLES.

I added ldap_schema=rfc2307bis to sssd.conf

The reason some groups were listed was because those groups had the objectClass sambaGroupMapping.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `getent group`,  do you see all the groups you expect to see?  When you say, "only three LDAP groups are recognized per user", how do you know?  Are you running `groups`?  Or something else?

If you query the LDAP server with `ldapsearch`, do you receive more than three groups?  Servers often have a limit on the number of results they will return as the result of a single query.  Something like this might work (I'm just guessing, since I don't know the details of your setup):

```
ldapsearch -x -h your.ldap.server -LL objectlcass=posixgroup
```

If your server has a size limit, you may see this at the end of your output:

```
Size limit exceeded (4)
```

If the `ldapsearch` command does return more than three results...well, come back here and let me know and we'll figure out what to check next.

Comment: i ran id and compared to what I saw on the SLES servers